# constant loss and accuracy in Pytorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, data-science

I have created a binary classification model. During training the model I am getting both loss and accuracy as constant. I tried the same code for other datasets and it is giving the same thing in every case. How to fix this?
Here is the code

```
model=Model()
lossfn=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)
#training model
epochs=10
train_acc=[]
test_acc=[]
losses=torch.zeros(epochs)

#training over loops
for i in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    batchAcc=[]
    batchLoss=[]

    for X,y in train_loader:

        #forward pass
        yHat=model(X)

        #lossfunction
        loss=lossfn(y,yHat)

        #backprop
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        batchLoss.append(loss.item())
        # predictions=(torch.sigmoid(yHat)>0.5).float()
        predictions=yHat>0
        batchLoss.append(loss.item())
        batchAcc.append(100*torch.mean(((yHat>0) == y).float()))

    losses[i]=np.mean(batchLoss)
    train_acc.append(np.mean(batchAcc))

    #Evaluation mode
    model.eval()
    X,y=next(iter(test_loader))
    with torch.no_grad():
        yHat=model(X)
    test_acc.append( 100*torch.mean(((yHat>0) == y).float()))

    print(f'Epoch:{i+1} loss:{loss.item()} train accuracy:{train_acc[-1]} test accuracy:{test_acc[-1]}')
```

Output of the code

```
Epoch:1 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:2 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:3 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:4 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:5 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:6 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:7 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:8 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:9 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
Epoch:10 loss:0.6931471824645996 train accuracy:33.33646011352539 test accuracy:0.0
```

Comment: I think it's because you are doing `optimizer.zero_grad()` after your computation step, which means the weights aren't being updated.

Comment: @Sean At least provide the method by which it can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are wrong, the order of

```
optimizer.zero_grad() # Clears the gradient for all parameters
loss.backward() # Populates the gradient for all parameters
optimizer.step() # Uses the gradient to update the parameters
```

is correct!

Likely culprit is this line:

```
loss=lossfn(y,yHat)
```

In your case, `y` is the ground truth and `yHat` is the prediction (which is confusing in the usual convention, hence the mistake).

However, PyTorch losses expect the prediction first and the target as the second argument; the gradient is not propagated correctly through the targets. Therefore, you should change it to

```
loss=lossfn(yHat,y)
```

Or even better, call `yHat` the ground truth target and `y` the prediction.

Answer (score -1):

#backprop should come in the following order

```
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.grad_zero()
```

This should fix this!!

Comment: That's not true, it would be a problem if `zero_grad` was between `backward` and `step`, but that's not the case (see the answer above)